# How does ASP.Net Cookieless work ?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, cookieless, session-state

I try to set the `<sessionstate />` in my web.config but I don't know what are they.
I would like to know about ASP.Net `<SessionState cookieless="" />`.

```
<sessionState cookieless="*****">
```

1. AutoDetect
2. UseCookies
3. UseDeviceProfile
4. UseUri
5. true
6. false

Let me know with short note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Specifies how cookies are used for a Web application.
>
> The cookieless attribute can be one of the following possible values.
>   The default is the UseCookies value.
>
> Note  When you configure an AJAX-enabled ASP.NET Web site, use only the
>   default value of UseCookies for the cookieless attribute. Settings
>   that use cookies encoded in the URL are not supported by the ASP.NET
>   AJAX client script libraries.
>
> **Value** Description
>
> **AutoDetect**    ASP.NET determines whether the requesting browser or device supports cookies. If the requesting browser or device supports
>   cookies, AutoDetect uses cookies to persist user data; otherwise, an
>   identifier is used in the query string. If the browser or device
>   supports cookies, but cookies are currently disabled, cookies are
>   still used by the requesting feature.
>
> **UseCookies**    Cookies persist user data, regardless of whether the browser or device supports cookies.
>
> **UseDeviceProfile**  ASP.NET determines whether to use cookies based on the HttpBrowserCapabilities setting. If the HttpBrowserCapabilities
>   setting indicates that the browser or device supports cookies, cookies
>   are used; otherwise, an identifier is used in the query string.
>
> **UseUri**    The calling feature uses the query string to store an identifier, regardless of whether the browser or device supports
>   cookies.

have also a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Note When you configure an AJAX-enabled ASP.NET Web site, use only the default value of UseCookies for the cookieless attribute. Settings that use cookies encoded in the URL are not supported by the ASP.NET AJAX client script libraries.

Well i'm using ASP.Net Ajax in Combination with `<sessionState cookieless="true">` and never experienced any problems... I'm Using an Updatepanel as well as an ASP Accordion on different pages.