# ASP.NET adds an extra info at the end of the URL. How to avoid it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.net website, the link to

```
http://scarab.ineo.be/Catalog.aspx?id_rayon=0000000015
```

is redirected automatically to

```
http://scarab.ineo.be/Catalog.aspx?id_rayon=0000000015#.Uyr5GPnWWi0.
```

Why is `#.Uyr5GPnWWi0` added ?

I thought it was something regarding the sessionState. In the web.config, the sessionsState is

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=....\SQL2008R2; integrated security=false; user id=sa; password=...." />
```

Is it possible to avoid this extra info at the end of the URL ?

Comment: I dont get the additional hash in the query string when i navigate to your URL's

Comment: Is this SPAM? I didn't get any hash

Comment: no, i get the hash tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks nothing like a sessionState issue, it looks EXACTLY like the AddThis plugin hash for tracking...

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/352733-how-to-remove-hash-from-url-

If you're using AddThis it will add a hash to all links. You can turn this off by adding the following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
</script>
```

**Edit:**

I just took a look at your website, and you are using AddThis. You also have the following code in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": true };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-510a8b7d07484835"></script>
```

Notice how you have the config for addressBar tracking set to true.

You need to turn this off.

Comment: I have to agree that it does seem a short querystring for cookieless... perhaps you are right!

Comment: Just took a quick look at his site, hes using the AddThis plugin.

Comment: You are 100% right : data_track was used and setting data_track_addressbar to false fixed this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the sessionstate. Normally Asp.Net webforms handles this by setting a cookie. So that the server side can determine which user is which.

But if you have `sessionState` in the web.config configured to be cookieless, it will append a random string to each url to identify the users session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

[How does ASP.Net Cookieless work ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027653/how-does-asp-net-cookieless-work)

Comment: Just for the record cookieless sessions are serious security risk. Avoid!

Comment: Totally agree @Stilgar it is a bad practise.